# Angular 6+ resolver doesn't load video url

Tags: angular, angular-resolver

I am trying to load a video url after the data be loaded from the server. I am using a resolver but it doesn't work because the video is loaded before the data some times. What I am doing wrong?

**component.ts**

```
this.valuePairService.getName('myVideoUrl').then(
  (responseUrl: any) => {
    this.videoUrl =
      responseUrl.value === undefined && this.hasVideo
      ? '//player.vimeo.com/video/09452678?dnt=1' 
        : responseUrl.value;
  }
);
```

**resolver**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ValuePairServiceResolver implements Resolve<string> {
    constructor(private nameValuePairService: valuePairService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
        return this.valuePairService.getName('myVideoUrl');
    }
}
```

**routing module**

```
  {
    path: 'videos',
    resolve: { ValuePairServiceResolver },
    component: VideosComponent
  },
```

Comment: That's not how you should use it in the component. Check out the docs: https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Comment: Thank you @MaciejKasprzak I have taken a look to Angular documentation but that example doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax in the routing module is incorrect. You need to specify the property name which will contain the resolved value:

`resolve: { videoUrl: ValuePairServiceResolver }`

Also, you're not using it correctly in the component. You should inject `ActivatedRoute` to the constructor and then you'll be able to access the resolved data:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.data.subscribe(({ videoUrl }) => {
    // you can access videoUrl here
  });
}
```