# Resolved - ActivatedRoute angular unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-unit-test

I am facing an issue when testing this code:

```
constructor(
    private valuePairService: ValuePairService,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private service: Service,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data.subscribe(({ result }) => {
      this.video =
        result.value === undefined
          ? '//player.vimeo.com/video/65498532'
          : result.value;
    });
  }
```

In my test I have this provider added:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: { data: of({ value: 'test'}) }
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
  });
```

Any idea about how to test it? I am having this error when executing the test:

```
error properties: Object({ longStack: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem was that I was testing the observable in the wrong way. I was using "value" instead of "result". The solution in the unit test is as follows:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: { data: of({ result: 'test'}) }
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
  });
```

Comment: Your test double for the activated route doesn't have the same structure as the thing it's replacing, which makes it less than useful.

Comment: Think about what the code you're testing actually expects to receive in that subscription. Where does result come from, and why is it undefined when it should be an object with a value property?

Comment: Please note this isn't a helpdesk, if you have deadlines you need to manage that yourself: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest.

Comment: You are injecting mocked `ActivatedRoute` but you are using `Router` to get it, so it will not work.

Comment: Please include `constructor` code. How do you expect people to know what your component properties are and how are they set. We can guess, but that is just waste of the time most of the times.

Comment: @Antoniossss I have added the constructor

Comment: Is that a typo? `this.route.data.subscribe(({ result })` should be `this.route.data.subscribe(result=>...)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68821142/angular-6-resolver-doesnt-load-video-url/68821248#68821248

Comment: @Antoniossss it's parameter destructuring...

Comment: Black magic for me ;) ty. Still, why not `result`?

Comment: You probably don't want to destructure.. Also did you try debugging your test?

Comment: Don't edit your post with the answer but rather accept the actual answer that helped you ;)

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks to your hints I found the solution. I was desperate and I had the solution in front of me.

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand why you want to use destruct there, but it will not work for you

1. Even compiler says it is invalid since `result` is missing
2. it will yeld undefined

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-alzyr4?file=index.ts

Code

```
of({ value: 'test'})
  .pipe(map(name => `Hello, ${name}!`))
  .subscribe(v=>console.log("normal lambda",v));

  of({ value: 'test'})
  .pipe(map(name => `Hello, ${name}!`))
  .subscribe(({result})=>console.log("descruct",result));
```

results in

[image]

So yeah, since `result` is undefined, therfore you cannot get `.value` from it.

Use `this.route.data.subscribe(result => actions)` and it will work. Turn on `strict` mode, so typechecking will prevent you from making such mistakes in the future. and `noImplicitAny`

PS. `subscribe(({value})=> actions)` could work.

Comment: thank you for your interest @Antoniossss. I have found the solution.

Comment: I would say that I have shown you the problem, but ok.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The problem was that I was testing the observable in the wrong way. I was using "value" instead of "result". The solution in the unit test is as follows:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: { data: of({ result: 'test'}) }
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
  });
```